# Laravel Auth only hard coded users can log in

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I create a new user via `php artisan tinker` I can use my login form to login, when I create a new user via the web application I can't log in using the credentials.

**login function**

```
Route::post('login', function(){
    $user = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($user)){
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('flash_notice', 'Hello '.$user['username'].', you have Successfully logged in!');
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::to('login')->with('flash_notice', "Error");
    }

});
```

**create user function**

```
Route::post('user/create',function(){
            $newuser = new User;
            $newuser->username = Input::get('username');
            $newuser->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $newuser->save();
});
```

I run the same 4 lines in artisan tinker to hard code a user into the database, and they can login, when I've created a user via the form, they show up in the database but are unable to log in.

What is going on?

Comment: Did you made sure the users created are activated?

Comment: @seblaze Activated? I'm not sure what you mean, I ran the same 4 lines of code in the create user function in tinker and users are created the same.

Comment: I just tested your code and it logged me in/out . are you 100% sure  that you get the Inputs correctly ? Also , are they any difference in the users table ( the users created with tinker and users created in your post route ? )

Comment: @seblaze *hangs head in shame* a capital p on the password input name was the problem. FML. Thankyou.

Comment: lol, glad you managed to solve it out :)